# Bash find char and remove all to the right

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hello all here is my issue in Bash,
I am trying to find the second occurrence of a char in particular '_' and once i find it remove that char and any other char to the right  of it. Here is the visualization:

```
String: foo_bar_v20.9_FUBAR
Output : foo_bar
```

Main issue is i can't find the best way to locate the second '_' and once there i should use its location to do something like this:

```
echo $editedString | cut -c 2ndUnderlineLocation- | rev
```

-Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$ string="foo_bar_v20.9_FUBAR"
$ [[ $string =~ ([^_]*_[^_]*)_ ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}     # First capture group
foo_bar
```

The capture group captures all non-`_` characters prior to the first `_`, the
first `_`, and all non-`_` characters prior to the next `_`.

---

(There is also this monstrosity which is POSIX-compliant...

```
echo ${string%_${string#${string%%_*}_*_}}
```

but that's best avoided unless absolutely necessary. It looks terrible, but you can build it up step by step as follows:

```
# What appears just before the first _?
$ x=${string%%_*}
$ echo $x
foo
# Use that as a prefix to remove, along with everything up to the next _
$ y=${string#${x}_*_}
$ echo $y
v20.9_FUBAR
# Remove *that* as a suffix
$ echo ${string%_${y}}
foo_bar
```

)

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick, thank you this makes much more sense that what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
echo "foo_bar_v20.9_FUBAR" | rev | sed -r 's/.*_(.*_.*)/\1/g' | rev
```

As far as I know, `sed` does not support non-greedy matching, so `rev` is used here.